# Inside flexbox, how would you place horizontally center in screen (not parent div)?

Tags: flexbox, material-ui

I was customizing a responsive drawer demo[below] so that main content is placed center in screen (not parent div) and it has maxWidth: 640px (just like [podcasts.google.com](https://podcasts.google.com)). How would you do that?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mln3e?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check attached Demo. I have forked your demo and updated.

Edit: updated the demo to make typography component in center of screen by ignoring the drawer width.

```
...
<Box
  component="main"
  sx={{
    ...
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
    position: "absolute",
  }}
>
  <Toolbar />
  <Box maxWidth="640px">
    <Typography paragraph>
    ...
  </Box>
...
```

[image: Edit ResponsiveDrawer Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is center to the parent div. Is it possible to center <Typography paragraph> in the center of a "screen" as if there's no drawer on desktop?

Comment: Yes, you can update the width property and add position: absolute property. check updated codesandbox

Comment: but this will give issue, typography paragraph will go under the drawer when screen width goes below 1120px.( 640 maxwidth  and 240 drawer width) will check further on this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: updated the position property to add the lg breakpoint. i guess this is better.

Comment: podcasts.google.com hides drawer as soon as typography overwraps a drawer. Thank you for your help! I accepted your answer.